# Unity:How to check if area inside camera view?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building a zombie survival game, in the game I have some game objects that act as spawn point to the zombies.I want to spawn the zombies when the spawn point is not in the camera view ,so how can I check if the spawn point is outside the camera view so as to spawn them.

Down below is my enemy spawn script.

**Enemy Spawn**

```
public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;       // Reference to the player's heatlh.
    public GameObject enemy;                // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
    public float spawnTime = 3f;            // How long between each spawn.
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;         // An array of the spawn points this enemy can spawn from.


    void Start ()
    {
        // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
        playerHealth = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
    }


    void Spawn ()
    {
        // If the player has no health left...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f)
        {
            // ... exit the function.
            return;
        }

        // Find a random index between zero and one less than the number of spawn points.
        int spawnPointIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

        // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position and rotation.
        Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could check to see if the spawn position is -z in relation to the camera, as a simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GeometryUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.html).[`TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html) to test the point.

```
bool IsVisible(Vector3 pos, Vector3 boundSize, Camera camera)
{
    var bounds = new Bounds(pos, boundSize);
    var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
    return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, bounds);
}
```

See http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/560147/view.html and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/227806/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-is-completely-visible.html

Comment: But i alread have spawn points, and i just want to check whether they are inside the viewpoints

Comment: Just use `IsVisible()` to test your spawn points with a bounds of a proper size.